# Query to Find Values from Multiple Columns in One Table to Multiple Columns in Another (in any order)?

Tags: sql

I have a table of records that has 40 different columns of attributes for each of those records (1mil+ rows). Right now I have those attributes in a True/False (0 or 1) format- but can change it to match the same format as used in the next table if I need to...

I have another table with all possible combinations of those attributes, from 2 to 4 different ones per combination, in any order (60,000+ combinations in all).

```
tblCombo (62,000+ rows)
============================================
ComboNum col1      col2      col3     col4
--------------------------------------------
1        Att13     Att16     Att2     Att9
2        Att1      Att5      Att9     null
3        null      Att4      Att16    Att8
4        Att2      null      null     Att14


tblRecords (1mil+ rows)
=========================================
RecNum Att1   Att2   Att3   Att4 (up to Att40)
-----------------------------------------
1       1      1      0      0
2       0      0      0      1
3       1      1      1      1
4       1      1      0      0

EXPECTED RESULT
=========================
ComboNum     RecNum
-------------------------
1              7
1             23
1             24
2             14
2             23
3             62
3             1,201
3             2,243
```

I am trying to find all the record numbers for each combination number. The tricky part is the attribute can be in any column of the combination table, and each record can be used multiple times by different combinations.

How do I go about doing this is SQL? I suspect I need to do joins across multiple columns, but not exactly sure how to do that.

Thank you!

Comment: why is this tagged sqlite and mysql?

Comment: show sample data _and desired results given that sample data_

Comment: Because I can use either MySQL, SQLite, MariaDB, etc etc.

Comment: I'll try to provide a better data sample in the original post...

Comment: ok,original post updated w/ better example/expected result. Again, if it makes it easier, I can change the tblRecords so that instead of using a 0/1 in the values, it would use the ATT# instead- if that makes it easier to match up? THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

A normalised design:

```
Id   ComboNum att   
-------------------
101 1 Att13     
102 1 Att16     
103 1 Att2     
104 1 Att9
105 2 Att1      
106 2 Att5      
107 2 Att9    
108 3 Att4      
109 3 Att16    
110 3 Att8
111 4 Att2
112 4 Att14
```

You can use this to create that...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_old_table;

CREATE TABLE my_old_table
(ComboNum SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,col1      VARCHAR(12) NULL
,col2      VARCHAR(12) NULL
,col3      VARCHAR(12) NULL
,col4      VARCHAR(12) NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_old_table VALUES
(1,'Att13','Att16','Att2','Att9'),
(2,'Att1','Att5','Att9',null),
(3,null,'Att4','Att16','Att8'),
(4,'Att2',null,null,'Att14');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_new_table;

CREATE TABLE my_new_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY) 
SELECT combonum, col1 att FROM my_old_table WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL
UNION 
SELECT combonum, col2 FROM my_old_table WHERE col2 IS NOT NULL
UNION 
SELECT combonum, col3 FROM my_old_table WHERE col3 IS NOT NULL
UNION 
SELECT combonum, col4 FROM my_old_table WHERE col4 IS NOT NULL;


SELECT * FROM my_new_table;
+----+----------+-------+
| id | combonum | att   |
+----+----------+-------+
|  1 |        1 | Att13 |
|  2 |        2 | Att1  |
|  3 |        4 | Att2  |
|  4 |        1 | Att16 |
|  5 |        2 | Att5  |
|  6 |        3 | Att4  |
|  7 |        1 | Att2  |
|  8 |        2 | Att9  |
|  9 |        3 | Att16 |
| 10 |        1 | Att9  |
| 11 |        3 | Att8  |
| 12 |        4 | Att14 |
+----+----------+-------+
12 rows in set (0.01 sec)

ALTER TABLE my_new_table ADD UNIQUE(combonum,att);
Query OK, 15 rows affected (0.18 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. How do I achieve this tho?

Comment: I guess I don't understand still. This unpivots the tblCombo Table- but doesn't match up which records contain which combinations? Am I missing something?

Comment: To get where you're going, you'd want to start from here

Comment: Yes, I understand that... but then what? I'm not seeing how to figure out if the entire Combo is matched up, or merely individual ones? Do I have to re-pivot it somehow? I really appreciate any additional explanation you can give!

Comment: The next step is to unpivot the records table, using the same technique, so you'd have a table of around 20 million rows (no need to store the zeros)

Comment: ok... and then do an inner join between both tables?

Comment: Essentially, yes.